# Plugin com.android.application not found when running app in android studio chipmunk canary 7

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I had downloaded android studio chipmunk canary 7  and faces this problem :

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.0-alpha07', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.2.0-alpha07', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.2.0-alpha07')
  Searched in the following repositories:
```

please any help ??

Comment: Welcome to the community; `Is there anyone how faces this kind of issue?` is not that good title; instead to have a better response you'd change that to something that is succinct and descriptive to the issue.

Comment: Please change the title to be more specific. E.g. "Plugin com.android.application not found when running app in android studio chipmunk canary 7"

Comment: facing the same problem after upgrade from '7.1.3' to '7.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

plugins {

```
id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0-rc02' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0-rc02' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
```

}

Update plugins in your build gradle file